# Postgres Check Constraint definition

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a query to list the `check constraints` in a database along with its constraint definition.
I am not able to find a column to find the check constraint definition just like the `search condition` column in `oracle` `all_constraints` table.
Is there a PG alternate for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The catalog pg_constraint stores check, primary key, unique, foreign key, and exclusion constraints on tables and contype column saves data about the type of the constraint i,e

```
c = check constraint
f = foreign key constraint
p = primary key constraint
u = unique constraint
t = constraint trigger
x = exclusion constraint

select pgc.conname as constraint_name,
       ccu.table_schema as table_schema,
       ccu.table_name,
       ccu.column_name,
       pg_get_constraintdef(pgc.oid) 
from pg_constraint pgc
join pg_namespace nsp on nsp.oid = pgc.connamespace
join pg_class  cls on pgc.conrelid = cls.oid
left join information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu
          on pgc.conname = ccu.constraint_name
          and nsp.nspname = ccu.constraint_schema
where contype ='c'
order by pgc.conname;
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm able to get the required info from pg_get_constraintdef(pgc.oid) from your query.