# How to get SQL used to create a constraint in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I can use the pg_indexes view to get the SQL used to create an index (as in the sql in this question: [How to get indexes, primary keys, and all constraints for a schema in PostgreSQL using standard sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75185876/how-to-get-indexes-primary-keys-and-all-constraints-for-a-schema-in-postgresql/75186685?noredirect=1#comment132677864_75186685)).

Is there a way to get the SQL for constraints in PostgreSQL?  I'm not seeing a pg_constraints table and the information I'm finding on line isn't pointing me to a solution, for example, these are some of the hits coming up when I Google the terms (postgresql get sql for constraint).

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206562/postgres-read-constraints-definition

[Postgres Check Constraint definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67999205/postgres-check-constraint-definition)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-query-to-display-all-the-existing-constraints-on-a-table/

Comment: "*I'm not seeing a pg_constraints table*" - [pg_constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html)

Comment: pg_constraints that is parallel to pg_indexes (i.e. has the constraint_definition where pg_indexes has index_definition)

Comment: `select  pg_get_constraintdef(oid) from pg_constraint where conname =  <constraint_name>;`